# After rebuilding the application on react-native in 0.70.0, avatars from Google stopped loading

Tags: react-native, image, avatar

On react-native v0.68.2 - works

On react-native v0.70.0 - not works

'Image' not showing avatar from Google-server for sign-in:

```
<Image style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
source={{ uri: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AFdZuco5YkhulxjXcpR-YXEIQZ8r2uc0Ti0di-Bb_fzP=s96-c', }} />
```

But showing same avatar from another server:

```
<Image style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
source={{ uri: 'https://wordskills.ru/testAvatar.jpg' }} />
```

In the place where the avatar should be, - an empty space

The link to the avatar is standard from Google-sign-in, and obtained using '@react-native-google-signin/google-signin'
(sample: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AFdZuco5YkhulxjXcpR-YXEIQZ8r2uc0Ti0di-Bb_fzP=s96-c')

In search of a solution, I tried to use:

- Avatar from 'react-native-paper'
- Image from react-native
- Fresco
- react-native-fast-image

All solutions failed.

Any clue how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is just with avatars from Google-server for sign-in.
I tried moving the avatar to another server and it shows up from there. 
From another server, the same avatar is displayed:
<Image resizeMode={'cover'} source={{ uri: 'https://wordskills.ru/testAvatar.jpg', width: 50, height: 50 }} />
But from Google-server is empty space

Comment: I tried deploy bare project on react-native: "0.70.1" and tried this code:
`<Image source={{ uri: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AFdZuco5YkhulxjXcpR-YXEIQZ8r2uc0Ti0di-Bb_fzP=s96-c', width: 50, height: 50 }} />`
And Image doesn't display it. This image link is a **standart user logo from Google sign-in**

Answer (score 1):

I found a problem, it's a sanctions against the country from which the avatars are not loaded.
And when checing links to avatars in the browser, they were loaded from cash. My problem is that i live in country with bad politics. I am Russian, but I am against war.
To get out of the situation, I will place a script in the backend that will download the avatars to the backend-server and upload them to the application from it
Thanks all for participanting!